# server/client socket based application error

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, server

I'm using Eclipse and I receive this error the whole time. Don't know what to do....

I receive this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    SOK_1_SERVER cannot be resolved to a type
    SOK_1_SERVER cannot be resolved to a type

    at server1.server11.main(server11.java:9)
```

Client side

```
package server1;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.security.sasl.SaslClient;


public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SaslClient CLIENT = new SaslClient() ;
        CLIENT.run() ;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        Socket SOCK = new Socket("localhost", 444) ;
        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream()) ;
        PS.println("HELLO FROM SERVER!!");

        InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream()) ;
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR) ;

        String MESSAGE = BR.readLine() ;
        System.out.println(MESSAGE) ;
    }
}
```

Server side

```
package server1;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class server11
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SOK_1_SERVER SERVER = new SOK_1_SERVER() ;
        SERVER.run() ;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(444) ;
        Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept() ;
        InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR) ;

        String MESSAGE = BR.readLine() ;

        if (MESSAGE != null)
        {
            PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream()) ;
            PS.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post SOK_1_SERVER source code please.

Comment: I don't seem to have it. How should it look like...

Comment: should I have written the source code for it...

Comment: Yes, you should have written it. You can't use a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: some notes on usage:  In Java, we usually name classes with capital letters, e.g. "Server11" and "Client".  We reserver ALL_CAPS for constants, and we use lower-case for variables, e.g.: ServerSocket srvSock = new ServerSocket(444);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SOK_1_SERVER SERVER = new SOK_1_SERVER() ;
    SERVER.run() ;
}
```

SOK_1_SERVER must be the name of a class. Have you defined a class named SOK_1_SERVER?

I think what you probably mean there is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    server11 SERVER = new server11();
    SERVER.run() ;
}
```